# PLCCrypto Encryption Hanging

Tags: android, xamarin, cryptography, aes

I'm playing around with adding some encryption to a Xamarin Forms app.

The project is targeting .Net standard 2.0, building for Android 11.0 - API30.

I'm using the PCLCrypto 2.1.40-Aplha nuget package and attempting to encrypt with the following code:

```
public static void AES_Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] keyMaterial)
        {
            var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
            var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);

            // The IV may be null, but supplying a random IV increases security.
            // The IV is not a secret like the key is.
            // You can transmit the IV (w/o encryption) alongside the ciphertext.
            var iv = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);

            byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, iv);

            // When decrypting, use the same IV that was passed to encrypt.
            //byte[] plainText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, cipherText, iv);
        }
```

Where both data and key-material are utf8 bytes of a string (so not-null terminated in the array).

My issue is the call to WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt is hanging and causing the app to hang.

Am I missing something with these calls ?

Edit 2 - This is occuring on every build version of PLCCrypto I have attempted so doesnt seem to be an alpha issue.

Comment: Must be throwing a exception, did you check the device output?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I edited to emphasise a hang rather than crash - I see nothing of note on the output. Pausing execution I see the thread is running not native code (I assume the encryption). I can set a debug point at the Encrypt call so I'm confident this is what's causing the subsequent hang.

Comment: Logcat must say something eventually

Comment: How do you call `AES_Encrypt`? Have you tried adding a try/catch around to see if an exception is actually thrown? Did you ensure that you have the NuGet package installed both in the shared code, but also in the Application project?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Well, the try catch helped. Apparently it did not like my key being less than 128. Though, on first attempt, a key of 128 in length still causes the same issue. More digging needed. Thanks